# WordPress widget default content

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am using a function to create my own widget in a custom theme, like this:

```
function my_sidebar_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'My Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'my-sidebar-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="my-sidebar-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebar_widget' );
```

This works fine, mostly. The problem is that when my theme is activated on a fresh instance of WordPress, this widget automatically adds in a search bar, recent posts and recent comments.

My question: Is there a function that can remove the content of all widgets (or specific widgets)? Or at the very least, a function that lets you dynamically add default content into the widget (I'd just make it display an empty space)?

Just to be clear, I don't want to unregister the widget, I just don't want it to automatically add in a search bar, recent posts and recent comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some very convoluted solutions to this problem, but after looking in the database I realised there is a much easier way.

Upon theme activation, just update this option with nothing:

```
update_option( 'widget_block', '' );
```

Problem solved. Just bear in mind that this will blank the widgets every time the theme is activated.